# How to make this JavaScript function be an equivalent to PHP's "print_r"?

Tags: php, javascript, debugging

I have this code so far:

```
function print_r( obj ) {
    if((typeof(obj)) == 'object' ) {
        var output = [];

        for(var x in obj) {
            if((typeof(obj[x])) == 'object') {
                output.push( print_r(obj[x]) );
            } else {
                output.push( x + ' => "' + obj[x].toString() + '"' );
            }
        }

        return output.join("\n");
    }

    return obj;
}
```

It does some basic recursion, but it's not good at this point.

How can I make this JavaScript function behave as PHP's [print_r function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)?

**EDIT:** With tab indents if the loop accours on a new object within the parent object.

Comment: Do you want to show the output exactly as print_r function? or Your aim is to just display the variables in human readable format?

Comment: Yes, excatly... What I want to is to solve the recursion problem and the "tab indention".

Comment: Do you just want this for debugging? Then use `console.log` and use your browser's JS console.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));

Comment: I don't want to use console.log or JSON.strinfy(). I want this function working! :) Thanks.

Comment: `2` means 2 space. You can give any number you want.

Comment: You could peek at http://phpjs.org/functions/print_r/

Comment: I honestly don't understand why you'd want to write a `print_r` clone when the console exists. But if you are going to do this, at the very least, you'll need to handle recursive object structures, otherwise you'll get into an infinite loop as soon as someone does `print_r(window)`.

Comment: @Spudley I am aware of that. That's why I want to slove this problem without using "console".

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that -- the console handles infinite loops by only expanding the tree as you ask for it. There's no issue with the console there: `console.dir(window)` will not get you stuck an infinite loop.

Comment: But anyway, if you want to avoid recursion issues, you'll have to back-track up the treee of objects and compare the current object with all the items up the tree. If you get the same object, then you've got a recursive tree, and you need to just print "recursion" instead of continuing down the tree. Either that, or the simpler option is simply to have a fixed max limit to the depth of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Install Firebug for your browser do this:

```
console.log(myvar);
```